# Swift create a button as a class variable / member variable

Tags: swift

This should be super straightforward. Here's what I am trying to do:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{
    var leftBarButton: UIButton;
    var rightBarButton: UIButton;

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

But I am getting an error that viewController has no initializers. I know I need to give the variables default values, so I tried:

```
var rightBarButton: UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as UIButton;
```

But that's giving me an error about multiple declarations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this

```
var rightBarButton: UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)
```

You need to intialize the button, but if you're not planning to change it I suggest you change it to `let`

Comment: or more succinctly: `var rightBarButton = UIButton(type: .System)`

Comment: Yup. Though he'll probably need a constant button, so: `let rightBarButton = UIButton(type: .System)`